# Analysis: Finding the derivative of a two variable function.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Question: find the derivative of $f(x,y)=(cos(x)cosh(y),sin(x)sinh(y))$ at the point (p,q).

I am fairly stuck here as each variable is in each component so I cant simply take the partial of each component and say that that is the derivative. So I am not sure how to proceed, any hints or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems that you are supposed to find the total derivate.

Comment: I have also seen such questions where they asked for the gradient or directional derivative. Are there any suggestions for a solution? Maybe we can reproduce what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_1(x,y)=\cos (x) \cosh (y)$ and $f_1(x,y)=\sin (x) \sinh (y)$ . Then

$f'(p,q)$ is the Jacobi-matrix of $(f_1,f_2)$.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I didn't know what justification there was of using the Jacobian matrix

Comment: What you need to do is use the definition of "derivative" for function of two variables found in that book.  If there is no such definition, then you have to start with: there is no definition in this book, so I will assume "derivate"means Jacobi matrix.

Comment: The Frechet derivative is just the Jacobian matrix in this case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative#Finite_dimensions